# powershell script to make array elements as the keys of hashtable

Tags: powershell

I want to assign all the array elements as the keys of hash table. For Example...

```
# arrays
$k=@(1,2,3)
$v=@("one","two","three")

# hashtable
$table=@{}
```

I want output like this:

```
$table={1="one",2="two",3="three"}
```

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
0..($k.count-1) |
    Foreach-Object -Begin {
        $table=[ordered]@{}
    } -process {
        $table.Add($k[$_],$v[$_])
    }
```

Assuming each array is the same size, you can loop through your indexes and grab elements at the same index from both arrays. The `Add(key,value)` method adds new key-value pairs to your hash table.

Answer (score 0):

You can also accomplish this with a for each loop to be able to easily track the index between both arrays

```
$k = @(1, 2, 3)
$v = @("one", "two", "three")

$table = @{}

for ($i=0; $i -lt $k.Length; $i++){
    $table[$k[$i]] = $v[$i]
}
```

*Note*: this is also somtimes referred to as "zipping" two arrays